# Fatal error: Allowed memory size при работе с PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

При работе с библиотекой PHP spreadsheet   возникает такая ошибка:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 20480 bytes) in
>   /home/xxxxx/xxxxx/www/save_excel/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Collection/Cells.php
>   on line 159.

Xls файл заполняется частями, первый вызов 3 000 строк, второй + 3 000 строк, при третьем вызове возникает ошибка с памятью.

Comment: попробуйте запустить

Comment: Скрипту не хватает памяти, попробуйте либо увеличить ее, либо ограничить длину цикла